# Populating table in a partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have two model classes,

```
public class Claims //Goes into main view
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ClaimName { get; set; }
    public List<ClaimDetails> ClaimList { get; set; }
}

public class ClaimDetails //Class I want in my partial view
{
    public int ClaimNumber { get; set; }
    public string Client { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

My controller,

```
public class ClaimsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Claims claims = new Claims();
        claims.Id = 1;
        claims.ClaimName = "Ashton";
        return View(claims);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SearchList(string enterdNumber)//On click of button I come here using ajax call
    {
        ClaimDetails cD = new ClaimDetails();
        Claims cms = new Claims();
        cms.ClaimList = new List<ClaimDetails>();
        cD.ClaimNumber = 10;
        cD.Client = "Ashton";
        cD.Amount = 2900;
        cD.Type = "Vendor";
        cms.ClaimList.Add(cD);
        ClaimDetails cDD = new ClaimDetails();
        cDD.ClaimNumber = 10;
        cDD.Client = "Ashton";
        cDD.Amount = 2900;
        cDD.Type = "Vendor";
        cms.ClaimList.Add(cDD);

        return PartialView("SearchList",cms);
    }
```

My main view in which I want my partial view to be rendered,

```
@using BusinessLayer
@model BusinessLayer.Claims
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Id):@Model.Id
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ClaimName):@Model.ClaimName
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="searchNumber" placeholder="Enter the number" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <button id="searchBtn" type="button">Search</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @Html.Partial("SearchList",Model.ClaimList)
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#searchBtn").on("click", function () {
            var enteredNum = $("#searchNumber").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Claims/SearchList",
                data: { enterdNumber: enteredNum }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

My partial view,

```
@model BusinessLayer.Claims
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Claim Number</th>
        <th>Client</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Type</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
        @if (Model.ClaimList != null)
        {
            foreach(var item in Model.ClaimList)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.ClaimNumber</td>
                    <td>@item.Client</td>
                    <td>@item.Amount</td>
                    <td>@item.Type</td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My control comes to my partial view page, which I confirmed using breakpoint, it also iterates through the foreach loop but still does not put rows into my table..Help to know where I am going wrong is appreciated, or may be my approach to partial view is itself wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning a partial view but you're not doing anything with it. You need to include the `success` callback in the ajax function and add the partial view to the DOM

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("SearchList", "Claims")', // use this
    data: { enterdNumber: enteredNum },
    dataType: 'html', // add this
    success: function(response) {
        $('#someElement').html(response); // add this (adjust id to suit)
    }
});
```

and assuming you want to update the existing partial, add an `id` attribute to the existing container

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="someElement"> // add id attribute
        @Html.Partial("SearchList",Model.ClaimList)
    </div>
</div>
```

Side notes:

1. You may want to consider including the <`table>` and `<thead>`
   element in the main view and have the partial only return the
   `<tbody>` elements to minimize the data transfered in each ajax
   call.
2. Your method appears to be just getting data based on a filter, so
   the method could be a GET rather than a POST